# Installing Numba on a Cluster (Compute Canada) using virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, cluster-computing, numba

I am trying to install Numba on a cluster so I can run my Jitted python codes on there. However I keep running into an error with "libllvmlite.so" when I try to import Numba. This is done on the Cedar cluster using virtualenv. Numba is installed using pip (and also tried pip3).

I start off my activating my enviroment using (... is the directory to my enviroment folder) :
`source ~/.../ENV/bin/activate`.
Then I use pip to install Numba (I've also tried used pip uninstall to remove and reinstall Numba).
However when I load up Python 3.7.0 on my enviroment, I obtain an error whenever I try to import Numba.

I use pip show to check versions: Python 3.7.0, Numba 0.53.1, llvmlite 0.36.0.

Here is the output of my terminal:

```
(ENV) [04:12:46] patrick7@cedar1 > [~/projects/def-mann/patrick7/diffusioncluster]python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Sep 25 2018, 18:19:16)
[GCC 5.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numba
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/patrick7/projects/def-mann/patrick7/diffusioncluster/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from numba.core import config
  File "/home/patrick7/projects/def-mann/patrick7/diffusioncluster/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/config.py", line 16, in <module>
    import llvmlite.binding as ll
  File "/home/patrick7/projects/def-mann/patrick7/diffusioncluster/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/llvmlite/binding/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .dylib import *
  File "/home/patrick7/projects/def-mann/patrick7/diffusioncluster/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/llvmlite/binding/dylib.py", line 3, in <module>
    from llvmlite.binding import ffi
  File "/home/patrick7/projects/def-mann/patrick7/diffusioncluster/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/llvmlite/binding/ffi.py", line 191, in <module>
    raise OSError("Could not load shared object file: {}".format(_lib_name))
OSError: Could not load shared object file: libllvmlite.so
```

I have tried other solutions found online (reinstall, try different versions...), so far none has worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem.

What I've tried and didn't work:

- Install llvmlite using pip manually
- Downgrade to Numba version 0.43 since its the oldest version compatible with Python 3.7
- Uninstall (llvmlite numpy and numba) and reinstalling Numba (which automatically installs it's dependancies) after upgrading Pip to the latest version

What worked:

- Upgrading Python from 3.7.0 to 3.7.10

It seems like for Python version >= 3.7.3, the default command `pip install numba` works flawlessly!

Thanks for reading!